# Can 'default' be an adverb?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

Consider the following sentence:

> Whenever possible, default and explicitly mapped names are honored as written.

It seems to me that default and explicitly both talk about how the names are mapped, and thus default would also be an adverb, but I don't see default listed as an adverb in the dictionary.

But they could also be nouns when written as thus:

> Whenever possible, default and explicit mapped names are honored as written.

What would be the clearest way to write this and can 'default' be an adverb as shown above.

Another pass at the sentence might read:

> Whenever possible, default mapped names and explicitly mapped names are honored as written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this works?

> Whenever possible, explicit and default mappings are honored as written.

Comment: This seems the least ambiguous option so far. I am left wondering how implicit and default would differ, but that is a whole other matter probably beyond my pay grade.

Comment: I also think this is the best so far.

Answer (score 3):

I parse the sentence as "default names are honored as written and explicitly-mapped names are honored as written."

"Explicitly mapped" would therefore be a phrasal adjective, but leaving out the hyphen in such cases is so common, it is difficult to be sure.

Comment: So the sentence needs to change then, because your parsing is not what I am trying to say.

Comment: @WilliamKF: I parsed the sentence in the same way as horatio - so you probably do want to rephrase the sentence :)

Answer (score 3):

For the meaning you apparently want, try "names mapped both explicitly and by default".

Comment: +1. I agree, but the problem is that then the rest of the sentence becomes kind of awkward.

Comment: Seems a bit awkward: "Whenever possible, names mapped, both explicitly and by default, are honored as written. "

Answer (score 2):

As I understand the sentence, it's not about *defaultly mapped names*, but *default names*. That would make *default* an adjective, not an adverb.

Comment: My intention is to convey that the mapping was a default mapping, not that the names were defaulted.

Comment: @WilliamKF: Then you would have to write it differently to make that clear. The word *default* isn't widely used as an adverb, and it would take the form *defaultly* or *defaultedly* in that case. Perhaps "names mapped explicitly or by default" would be usable.

Answer (score 1):

Building on chaos's answer, and trying to make the sentence less awkward:

> Whenever possible, all names are
>   honored according to the mapping, whether it is explicitly or by default.

Comment: But they are honored as mapped, not as written.  That is, it is the written map that is honored.

Comment: This any better, then?

Comment: Hmm, the use of 'explicitly' in your sentence seems a bit awkward to me, plus I still don't think it quite has the correct meaning.  How does my suggested answer read to you?

Comment: The separate answer (not the one at the end of your question) does sound much better.